# Tkinter program not loading

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess

Hi I am writing a basic GUI using python Tkinter. I can get it to show the interface, however when asking one of my buttons to call a subprocess, the GUI does not load, although there are no errors reported. here is the code for the buttons:

```
B = Tkinter.Button(root, text ="Reference fasta file", command = openfile).pack()
C = Tkinter.Button(root, text ="SNP file", command = openfile).pack()
D = Tkinter.Button(root, text ="Generate variant fasta(s)", command = subprocess.call(['./myprogram.sh','B','C'],shell=True)).pack()
```

If I do not include button "D" in my code, the GUI appears. Strangely if I include button "D" and pass a file that does not exist into subprocess.call, the GUI appears, but I get an error message saying file does no exist as expected.

why then does passing a program which does exist in the directory cause the program not to run, without an error message being passed?

Thanks very much

Comment: As command you need to pass a callable

Comment: ./myprogram is callable and has executable status

Comment: You have to pass a callable Python object as value of the `command` argument.  Which you don't -- you _call_ the `subprocess.call()` function, which executes the external script right away, and the pass the _return value_ of that call as command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've passed as command not a function but what is returned by a function (which of course may be a function).
So instead of:

```
D = Tkinter.Button(root, text ="Generate variant fasta(s)", command = subprocess.call(['./myprogram.sh','B','C'],shell=True)).pack()
```

you should call it like:

```
def click_callback():
    subprocess.call(['./myprogram.sh','B','C'],shell=True)

D = Tkinter.Button(root, text ="Generate variant fasta(s)", command = click_callback).pack()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
command = subprocess.call(['./myprogram.sh','B','C'],shell=True)
```

you run `subprocess` and result is assigned to `command=`.

`command=` expect only function name without `()` and arguments (as ambi said: python `callable` element)

Probably `subprocess` is running and script can't run rest of code.

Maybe you need

```
def myprogram()
    subprocess.call(['./myprogram.sh','B','C'],shell=True)

command = myprogram
```

Do you really need subprocess ?